# Does a Vietnamese student need a visa for a vacation to America?

Tags: visas, usa, vietnamese-citizens

I'm Vietnamese, and I am studying in Spain. I want to travel to America on my vacation just for 1-2 weeks. Do I need a visa? If I have to apply for a visa, how can I do that in Spain?

Answer (score 5):

Vietnamese citizens need a visa to visit the USA.  You should contact the USA Embassy in Madrid - http://madrid.usembassy.gov/ - to obtain the necessary forms and schedule an appointment to apply for the visa.

You will need to document why you are in Spain, but your school registration along with the EU visa you have in your passport would likely cover this (the embassy staff can tell you more).